# How can I get values from dynamically created ngx-star-rating in Angular 11?

Tags: angular

I am trying to create dynamic ngx-star-rating controls based on the results Database.
But I am confused at getting the input values forstar controls.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="pull-left">
    <ngx-star-rating id="rating1{{
    
            idx
    
          }}" name="ratValue[{{idx}}]" [disabled]="false" [ngModel]="ratValue[idx]
    
          " (onModelChange)="GetRatingValue($event)">
    
    </ngx-star-rating>
</div>
```

Comment: which version of anuglar you're using?

Comment: I'm using Angular 11